# Get a component by name in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a **component** in **extjs** store named `date`

How can i retrieve it *ExtJS*

Comment: What are you for a user? All of your questions got answered within the 3 minutes by always the same user. That is really weird.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try this :

```
var dateObj = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=date]');
```

Comment: you can't add methods show() and hide in such chain ... they wouldn't work

Answer (score 17):

The `name` property is normally used by fields and there is a much better way to fetch them as the `ComponentQuery`. So if this is about fields I strongly recommend you to use [findField()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-findField)
 instead of a `ComponentQuery`. You can use it like

```
formInstance.getForm().findField('NameOrId');
```

Comment: In handler for a button that is inside a panel: `var form = this.up('panel').getForm();` and then `form.findField('some-name');`